# SvelteKit + REST API: should I make fetch calls from +page.ts or +page.server.ts?

Tags: fetch, svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a webapp with SvelteKit with a data source being a REST API on a separate server (Django + Django REST Framework). My understanding is that I can leave SSR enabled and just make `fetch` calls to my REST API endpoints. Should I make these calls from `+page.ts` or `+page.server.ts`?

What about if I use session auth with my Django backend and I need to send back the session data to the backend?

Comment: It mostly depends on what you're going to use the data for. If you need it in the front end (say username, images, etc...) then put it inside of `+page.ts` if you need it in the backend (say, password authentication), use it inside of `+page.server.ts`

Comment: @JoshuaQ that's where I'm confused. When you say "e.g. password authentication", why does that need to be in `+page.server.ts` if all I'm doing is hitting an external REST API? Does it matter?

Comment: So, if you're using sensitive data, `+page.server.ts` is what you want to use, because the data won't be exposed to the front-end unless you return it out of the action (eg: the `load` action) hence password authentication. If you put that sensitive data inside of `+page.ts` it's exposed and people can easily intercept that data

Comment: @JoshuaQ what sensitive data would I be exposing? All I'm doing is hitting a publicly known REST API (granted with a strict CORS policy), passing through the username and password, and getting back an HttpOnly cookie.

Comment: Then the choice is up to you on which one you want to use

Answer (score 2):

@kevlar what you're proposing is completely fine.

As the docs tell you the page.server.ts files makes most sense when you have secret environment variables or API keys.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js

In your case where it is an open API and you have no secrets to hide the +page.ts makes perfect sense.

The scenarios where this is important would for example be when you want to protect the calls to the API, environment variables or if you're using SvelteKit as your actual backend where it will connect to databases etc.

Hope it helps clarify :)